# Parse JSON from array

Tags: php, json

I have this JSON response from YouTube v2: `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/youtube/uploads?orderby=published&max-results=1&alt=json`.

It only returns with one video entry **as I wanted**. I want to get the **title** of that video? I have currently used the following code:

```
$URL = file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/youtube/uploads?orderby=published&max-results=1&alt=json');
$readjson = json_decode($URL);
$title = $readjson->{'feed'}->{'entry'}->{'title'}->{'$t'};
echo $title;
```

but it looks like it's not a normal JSON tree, because it has an array in video `entry`
so my code didn't work. Any ideas how to get that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$title = $readjson->{'feed'}->{'entry'}[0]->{'title'}->{'$t'};
```

Comment: Note that `->{'a'}` is the same as `->a`

Comment: (although `->{'$t'}` is not the same as `->$t`)

Comment: @Eric yes that would be a PHP value, Thanks again